# Can $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] be spoofed?

Tags: php, security, cgi

I have a situation where I am opening a file based on the $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] variable.  I don't think this is spoof-able but would just like to confirm.  I do not want to make myself vulnerable to the reading of arbitrary files:

```
   <?
      $user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
      $fp = fopen("./$user.png","r");
   ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that username is whatever is specified by the remote user.

You need to verify password as well.  If password is verified by your server, and not your application, then you are probably okay.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, Yes, let me clarify... anything in `$_SERVER` comes from the server, but what shows up in the `REMOTE_USER` key is directly derived from client information provided for authentication.

Comment: yes but the server won't populate REMOTE_USER without successful authentication, so it can't be arbitrarily populated in absence of other security failings.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, "in absence of other security failings" is one way... configuring the server to accept everything and passing it through to your application is another.  Sure, `PHP_AUTH_USER` is generally used for this, but I've seen at least one situation where the server would pass everything through and let the application handle it.

Comment: the only thing that can be trusted in $_SERVER is REMOTE_ADDR, and that'll only be the final endpoint before reaching your server, e.g. the user's proxy server/nat gateway, not their actual IP.

Comment: It is strongly implied at the stage where my code is run that the user is properly authenticated.  User's can't even reach the directory where my script is run without being forced to a login page.  Thanks.

Comment: This means it depends on how your server is configured. If you use something like NTLM the server checks authentication and set REMOTE_USER accordingly. In this case it should be trust able. However, if you miss configure the server REMOTE_USER can be insecure.

Comment: Don't forget that the user can authenticate with one username, and spoof in another later.  If you're just checking that a username has been passed, then you aren't verifying anything and effectively letting anyone be anyone on your system, which generally isn't secure.